# Replace hyphen with integer sequence

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I would like to replace the hyphen in a string of the form n1-n2 with the integer sequence between n1 and n2 i.e. 3-9 becomes 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (ideally in Sublime text). Is this possible? All I know is how to find the strings, not replace them...

```
\d+-\d+
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems you need to write a specific app to do that. Regex by itself cannot increment a number found and then paste the value and repeat that operation several times. If there is no `4` in the matched/captured text, regex engine cannot generate it for you.

Comment: Nope, regex is pattern matching, i.e. it can only match patterns and nothing more. Sounds like you want some sort of tool (which you could simply create).

Comment: This [plugin](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/InsertNums) or [this one](https://github.com/eBookArchitects/Incrementor) might hold solution to your problem.